# How can I copy a machine learning model from one Elasticsearch server to another?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, xpack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm using Elasticsearch with X-Pack's ML module installed.

I have a machine learning model created on one server, but now I want to transfer that model to another Elasticsearch instance, so that it can be used there without having to re-run the ML job to build to model (because the model was built from a large dataset).

Is it possible to export a generated ML model from one instance of Elasticsearch and import it into another instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, all data are stored in indices named `.ml-*` which means that you can either do a snapshot and restore or use the reindex API (but beware of the mapping to use).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like you are correct.  I also found https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump which appears like it will let me export and import indexes, so I'll give that a shot too.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.